# pactbroker docker image connection issue with non-dockerized postgresql

Tags: postgresql, docker, pact, pact-broker, pact-jvm

I am using pact broker docker image present in

the same image is present in

I am not using docker image of postgresql. I have my own Postgres server hosted in

`172.15.16.23 (local ip), port 5432 , admin usaer as pactbrokeruser and password as 'password' and db name is pactbroker-db`.

I am setting environment variable as given in the documentation as

- PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_ADAPTER  = postgres
- PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_USERNAME = pactbrokeruser
- PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_PASSWORD = password
- PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_HOST = 172.15.16.23
- PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_NAME = pactbroker-db

I am using docker run command as

```
docker run --name pactbroker -e
PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_USERNAME=pactbrokeruser -e
PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_PASSWORD=password -e
PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_ADAPTER=postgres -e PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_HOST= 172.15.16.23 -e PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_NAME=pactbroker_db -p 80:80 dius/pact_broker
```

but still, the connection is not happening.In docker log, I am getting error "connection has not established" Could you please help me writing proper command of connecting dockerized pact-broker to non-dockerized postgresql.
---------------------------after comment from BEth-------------------
I have tried as per your suggestion. BUt environment variables are working fine.I have tried by editing docker compose file given in Git Project https://github.com/DiUS/pact_broker-docker   as below

version: '2'

services:

broker_app:
    image: dius/pact-broker
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    environment:
      PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_USERNAME: postgres
      PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_PASSWORD: Welcome123
      PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_HOST: 10.0.0.204
      PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_NAME: postgres

I have removed database image downloading part as I am using it externally. I have given my external Postgres data base details in the image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cREgY.jpg)

So as host I am giving the ip of the server, is it correct?

Comment: Check that you can connect to your postgres instance from the docker container manually: `docker exec -it <docker id> bash`

You should then be in a shell, use the CLI to check if you can establish a TCP connection to your postgres instance.

Also, it looks as though there is a space after `PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_HOST=`, please check that's not an issue.

Lastly, can you please fix the formatting of your post? It's very hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Can you test that the environment variables are correctly set by running the following command from somewhere that you have the postgres client installed

```
psql postgresql://${PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_USERNAME}:${PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_PASSWORD}@${PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_HOST}/${PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_NAME}
```

Can you also check if you have any firewall that might be blocking the connection.

Comment: I have tried but still it is failing. I have updated my main question with my database details and yml file details. PLease let me know if you need anything else.